# How would I create side scrolling text in PyGame?

Tags: python, scroll, pygame, weather

I am currently working on a weather application using the PyGame framework and it needs to have side scrolling text at the bottom, but I wouldn't know how to do it. I have looked for tutorials online and I have found things similar but not quite what I would like.

This is my code around the end, where all of the text is initalized.

```py
desc_text = desc.render(description, True, (255, 255, 255))
desc_rect = desc_text.get_rect()
desc_rect.center = (238, 740)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720), pygame.FULLSCREEN, vsync=1)

while running:
    try:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            elif event.type == QUIT:
                running = False
        screen.fill((0, 0, 125))
        screen.blit(header_text, header_rect)
        screen.blit(temperature_text, temperature_rect)
        screen.blit(wind_text, wind_rect)
        screen.blit(desc_text, desc_rect)
        pygame.display.update()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quitting...")
        running = False
```

[This is the text.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBZSZ.png)

I want it to be like a marquee, scrolling left to right endlessly.

Comment: `not quite what I would like` ... why were online examples not suitable?

Comment: online examples only showed scrolling text up or down but not left or right

Comment: Are you able to transpose the x and y values of your vertical scrolling example to make it scroll horizontally?

Comment: changing the x values does nothing, wonder if i could increment through the text.

Comment: we have no idea what `tutorials online` you saw. We can't read in your mind. You have to describe all details in question (not in comments).

Comment: I don't understand problem - why not run `header_rect.x -= 1` in every loop. And if you want to scroll many messages then better create on string. You may have to run the same text two times - one after another with offset `header_rect.width` - to get beginning after end. And when you get `header_rect.right == 0` then you have to move it to `header_rect.x += header_rect.width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what is the problem.

The simplest version which moves to left and when all text leave screen on left side then it shows it again on right need

- put on right side `rect.x = screen_rect.right`
- in every loop move `rect.x -= 1`
- in every loop check if it all text leave screen `rect.right <= 0` and move to right side `rect.x = screen_rect.right`

and you should start with this - and later try to create more complex version which repeat text at once after when there is space text.

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`; directly after import

FPS = 30

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))#, pygame.FULLSCREEN, vsync=1)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

description = " How would I create side scrolling text in PyGame? "

desc_text = font.render(description, True, (255, 255, 255))
desc_rect = desc_text.get_rect(left=screen_rect.right)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    try:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                
        # --- updates (without draws) ---
        
        desc_rect.x -= 5
        if desc_rect.right <= 0:            # if leave on left side
            desc_rect.x = screen_rect.right # then move to right side
            
        # --- draws (without updates) ---
        
        screen.fill((0, 0, 125))

        screen.blit(desc_text, desc_rect)
        
        pygame.display.update()
        
        clock.tick(FPS)   # slowdown to 30 FPS
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quitting...")
        running = False

pygame.quit()
```

To make more complex version you have to repeate the same text 2 or 3 times - so it needs to create 2 or 3 `rect` with offsets. First starts at `rect.x` second starts at `rect.x + rect.width` and third starts at `rect.x + rect.width + rect.width`. And for all of then you have to repeat (almost) the same code as in previous version. If you put all `rect` on list then it can be simpler.

Difference is: when it leave on left side then move to right by `rect.width * 3`

```
import pygame

# --- constants ---  # PEP8: `UPPER_CASE_NAMES`; directly after import

FPS = 30

# --- main ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960, 720))#, pygame.FULLSCREEN, vsync=1)
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 50)

description = " How would I create side scrolling text in PyGame? "

desc_text = font.render(description, True, (255, 255, 255))

# because text is short so I need 3 copies (with different offsets)
desc_rects = []

for i in range(3):
    rect = desc_text.get_rect(left=screen_rect.right)
    rect.x += rect.width * i  # add offset
    desc_rects.append(rect)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    try:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
                
        # --- updates (without draws) ---
        
        for rect in desc_rects:
            rect.x -= 5
            if rect.right <= 0:
                rect.x += rect.width * 3
            
        # --- draws (without updates) ---
        
        screen.fill((0, 0, 125))

        for rect in desc_rects:
            screen.blit(desc_text, rect)
        
        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(FPS)   # slowdown to 30 FPS        
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Quitting...")
        running = False

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: hi, i'd like to say thank you for your answer and thank you for helping me, but the text scrolls way too fast and any integer lower than 1 doesn't work for some weird reason. is there a solution?

Comment: pixels use integer values. You may have to use [time.Clock().tick()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) - i.e. `tick(30)` - to slowdown code to 30 FPS (Frames Per Second) on all computers. Or [time.get_ticks()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to check current time and use it to move text only every few milliseconds. Eventually you may use [time.set_timer()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to execute custom `event` every few milliseconds and this event you can use to run code which moves text.

Comment: in answer I added `tick(30)` and it moves slower - I even needed to add `rect.x -= 5` to move it faster.